# Android Studio - gradle task to execute after SYNC

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Is there a way to execute gradle task once after project Sync with Gradle files is complete?

I've tried to set task dependency to preBuild, as I've seen `gradle:build` is triggered when Sync is executing. But the problem is that dependency doesn't seem to work, task is not executed and I have to manually start the task after each Sync.

This is basically what I've tried so far

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...

task myTask {
    ...
}
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(myTask)
}
```

I've also tried to set task dependency to other tasks that I see are triggered (:generate{Something}), but that wasn't successful either.

Is there anything I can to do force the gradle task to be executed after each Sync?
I'm using Gradle 2.2.1 + Android Studio 1.0.2

Comment: The `generateDebugSources` task is run on project sync -- you can see this in the Gradle console.

Comment: I've tried to bind task that `generateDebugTestSources` depends on it (this one is executed as well with `generateDebugSources`), but that doesn't seem to help

Comment: `generateDebugSources` didn't work either, but I've managed to make it work without wrapping the dependency in `projectsEvaluated`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to trigger the task on every Sync event.
Apparently `gradle.projectsEvaluated` is either not executed at all when syncing, or it is executed after `build` task, so the solution is to get rid of it completely

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...

task myTask {
    ...
}

preBuild.dependsOn(myTask)
```

Answer (score 10):

Inside the Gradle menu (usually located on the upper right corner of Android Studio), there is a list of tasks. By right clicking on the task, it is possible to set `Execute After Sync`.

[image]

Comment: One drawback of this beautiful approach is that the flag is not stored in a VC-backed file. So, unfortunately, it does not scale to bigger developer teams.

Comment: There is now a solution for limitation I noted above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61285609/192373

Answer (score 5):

Some while ago JetBrains [extended their idea gradle plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/DSL-spec-v.-0.2) and now you can write something like

```
idea.project.settings {
  taskTriggers {
    afterSync tasks.getByName("myTask")
  }
}
```

You must apply the plugin, such as

```
plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext" version "0.7"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases):

> A Gradle build has three distinct phases
>
> **Initialization...**
>
> **Configuration** During this phase the project objects are configured.
> The **build scripts** of all projects which are part of the build are
> **executed**.
>
> **Execution...**

Our **build.gradle** files are **executed** during Configuration phase. Task is a class (we extend `org.gradle.api.DefaultTask` when developing them). So let's just call our task's `execute` method:

```
task myStandaloneTask(type: MyStandaloneTaskImpl){
    println("myStandaloneTask works!")
}

// let's call our task
myStandaloneTask.execute()

task myInsideGradleTask {
    println("myInsideGradleTask works!")
}

// let's call our task
myInsideGradleTask
```

where `MyStandaloneTaskImpl` is a Task developed in **buildSrc** or as **Standalone** project, [details](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:packaging_a_task_class)

P.S. No need to use parenthesis **()** after `myInsideGradleTask` because of **Groovy**